CountIF with distinct values
I am trying to make a countif -- time between 5am and 2pm-- then return "afternoon", for that part i got it right but I just realized that I was counting every row and some of them are duplicates.
This is a sale database, meaning there are several rows with the same order id (multiple items in one order), how can i count distinct orders based on timestamp?
I want to create chart that shows the number of sales per days of the week based on given time (categorized as morning, afternoon, night)
so far I have general formula counting every row without excluding duplicates>>
D is the column where I have my days of the week, B is the column where i have my timestamp as UTC (I need to show it as EDT), F is the column where I have my categories based on timestamp (morning, afternoon etc) and C is the column where I have my timestamps as EDT.
=COUNTIFS(D3:D5000,B3,F3:F5000,C2)
Where can I add the distinct to count unique rows based on order ID (which would be in column A)

select COUNTIFS(distinct D3:D5000,B3,F3:F5000,C2);

